# How do I print a specific value from a dictionary using key?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

So if I run this, I just get the list of hundreds of keys and values.

What I would like to know is how can I pull out a specific value from this dictionary?

i.e.: UserA - from keyword 'Users'

```
myuser = iam.list_users(
    PathPrefix='/'
```

)

Looking at the BOTO3, I want to pull out the EXAMPLE User 'Juan'

```
Expected Output:

{
'Users': [
    {
        'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/engineering/Juan',
        'CreateDate': datetime(2012, 9, 5, 19, 38, 48, 2, 249, 0),
        'PasswordLastUsed': datetime(2016, 9, 8, 21, 47, 36, 3, 252, 0),
        'Path': '/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/engineering/',
        'UserId': 'AID2MAB8DPLSRHEXAMPLE',
        'UserName': 'Juan',
    },
    {
        'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/engineering/Anika',
        'CreateDate': datetime(2014, 4, 9, 15, 43, 45, 2, 99, 0),
        'PasswordLastUsed': datetime(2016, 9, 24, 16, 18, 7, 5, 268, 0),
        'Path': '/division_abc/subdivision_xyz/engineering/',
        'UserId': 'AIDIODR4TAW7CSEXAMPLE',
        'UserName': 'Anika',
    },
],
'ResponseMetadata': {
    '...': '...',
},
```

}

Thank you!!

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, and what your current output or error messages are.

Answer (score 1):

Printing the values

users - your dictionary

user - value in dictionary

> user = users["UserKey"]
>
> print(user)

Comment: thank you for the response. excuse me if I am just asking the question incorrectly.